# Snapping and Tracing using QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, snapping, tracing

[image][image]When I split features or split parts, and using Enable Tracing, all I have is an uncontrolled snap to other existing features boundaries. As I start tracing it always go through anywhere in the map. Every time it connects to the other edge of polygon as you've seen in the image.

Comment: Seems like you forgot the image. Also, I doubt one image will suffice. Please provide before and after split screenshots, as well as the settings of your tracing tool. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Sorry I forgot the image to upload.. It's done.

Comment: Did you set the layer to snap to? Did you define tolerance and snapping mode (vertex, segment)? See: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html?#setting-the-snapping-tolerance-and-search-radius - Anyhow, a few more details about your problem would help finding a solution